# play video with Data iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video file that saved in fileManager encrypted, for security reason I don't want to save it or write it in filemanager without encryption. I would like to know can I play the video With Data. When I decrypt the file, the result become Data, so is there a way to play the video with Data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to play the video with data. You must write video data to temple directory and get url to play.
In case ensure security policy, you can delete the temple directory after play video